# Automatically object creation when class is imported without any other call in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I need create a library for an iOS application, that will be auto allocated without any other call excepting #import"nameOfHeader.h"

How can I do this.

Comment: Strange case. Will you not interact with allocated instance somehow in your code?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean importing a library by Reflection ? You ll have to code this anyway

Comment: Only in some cases if the programmer will want to use some addition functionality, but main idea is to be maximally simple to add to the project

Comment: I see, you have an answer, but I feel uncomfortable with that approach. I would just use singleton instantiated lazily. But, if you're ok with that - go for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add eg:

```
+ (void)load {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(sharedInstance) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

to the class which is imported

Comment: @ChetraruValera Glad to help ^^